# How to autoscale a pod using other metrics than memory and cpu in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

How to scale a pod using custom made resource? Suppose i want to scale my deployment when ever my url is hit 5 times or so. How can I do this? Please comment

Comment: I guess you mean using custom metrics for HPA feature ?
I will return to you soon with some examples based on GKE and StackDriver.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for on premise cluster, Also I found some sample, https://github.com/vishen/k8s-custom-metrics/blob/master/